# Use a virtualbox shared folder as mysql data storage

Tags: debian, mount, virtualbox, mysql

I am trying to use a vbox mysql server's (host: Debian 11, guest: Debian 11) shared folder to host its mysql data. Basically the guest machine runs mysql server and I would like to store its data in a vbox shared folder.

As many of you might already know, this is very hard because vbox shared folders don't let other users write into them, even if you add the user that has to write in the shared folder to the `vboxsf` group.

I have tried many different approaches such as using a soft link, (no writing permissions, starting the mysql process fails). I don't want to give up because, I'm not sure how, I have been able to achieve this on another virtualmachine with the same setup running Apache2 and putting Apache2 www folder in the vbox shared folder. I am now stuck with trying to mount it manually with the following command:

```
mount -t vboxsf -o remount,gid=106,uid=112,rw database /media/sf_database
```

However, i get the following result:

```
/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Could be running MySQL as the user who mounted the shared forward is better way? BTW, what is the purpose of this?

Comment: VMs can get corrupted or have issues. It's easier to have mysql database outside the virtualmachine.
Is it ok to run mysql as root?

Comment: I'm having troubles also doing that (running mysql as root in the VM)... could you advise, please?

Comment: Yes, it is hard and painful to misuse advanced specialized technologies. The advice is to explain why you are wanting to do such incredibly strange thing, probably, we'll be able to suggest a more rugged solution, which doesn't involve putting mysql data into vboxsf. Read here: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I don't want to install a more upgraded version of php (which is required by phpmyadmin) on the host machine because it is running a webapp that doesn't support it (I only use it through a vpn so it doesn't matter if php is old). Therefore phpmyadmin will refuse to run on the host machine. Keeping the db data on the guest is risky as the virtual hard drive might get corrupted and so on.

Comment: Why aren't you bothered that *host* hard drive might get corrupted? The odds are relatively the same. And, while with shared folders that won't be the problem, the lack of proper POSIX semantics in the vboxsf *will* get the database files corrupted nevertheless. Actually, this way you have much more likely to get it corrupted. Better ways to attack the problem: [Linux containers](https://linuxcontainers.org/) (your problem seems to be exact use case for this), [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System), [iSCSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISCSI), probably there are more.

Comment: Also, nothing mandates the placement of PHPMyAdmin and MySQL on the same system. You can install PMA in the VM, leave MySQL on the host machine and permit root connection to MySQL from PMA VM. This way you also avoid moving MySQL, not losing any performance. Actually, vboxsf was the worst idea ever. Also, I'd strongly suggest to *never* use Virtualbox for production (you're in Linux, use KVM or containers), and also to *not* to install PMA to the production server. It's place probably on the developer workstation, not on the server, and I strongly doubt it is ever useful at all.